# Jasmine Unit testing, method does not exist when accessing methods inside a directive

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I have the following situation, in my directive I have a method that is declared with "var methodname". I initialise my test but I keep getting an error saying the method does not exist. What am I missing from my test to get around this issue?

```
//my test 
    beforeEach(function () { 
       spyOn(scope, 'innerMethod'); -- fails here with method does not ae
    });

//my directive 

 link: function (scope, elm, attrs) {

   var innerMethod = function() { 
       //do something here
   }

  });
```

***Edit***
I ended up just mocking the functionality inside the jasmine test.

Comment: Unit testing is about testing the public API of your component. You cannot test or access a function scope method outside of its parent

Comment: @Phil, So I'm not able to test methods inside a directive?

Comment: You can attach the method to directive scope for easier unit testing. Something like this `scope._privateMethod = function() { ... }`.

Comment: @Jimi you can test what it does. For example, say it alters a `scope` property, you can call whatever ends up running the internal function and then test that `scope` is altered correctly.

Comment: Hmm I must have been doing it wrong. I tried to init the whole object as a constructor like : var myNewDirective = new myDirective(); spyOn(myNewDirective, 'innerMethod'); I still got the error method does not exist

Comment: You can't access function variables outside of function scope (in JS meaning of the word). spyOn tests methods, and 'method' is a member of some object, not an arbitrary function.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `innertMethod` is not attached to the directive's scope. Instead it only exists in the local scope of the directive.

For your tests to have access to `innerMethod` you need to attach it to the scope in the directive with `scope.innerMethod = function() { ... }` and then in your tests you can reference it from the directive, which must be injected.